# IP Messenger for CentOS 7

Tags: centos, installation, messenger

I'm Using CentOS 7 and trying to install IP messenger in it but not able to install it. Can anyone help me in installing any IP messenger. Any kind of help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: post the errors please

Comment: i tried yum install iptux it loads some cache data and then displays "no package iptux available"

Comment: download the rpm of iptux and install it http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/103822/is-there-any-ip-messenger-for-linux-centos

Comment: i downloaded it extract it then with root privilege i tried ./configure i get no package gconf-2.0 found

Comment: just download rpm file from link in my post and install it. it would be much easier.

Comment: you can get rpm version of gconf-2.0 [here](http://pkgs.org/download/libgconf-2.so.4) as well

Comment: @Shubham please make sure that you installed all the required dependencies. (I corrected my post). In your case the package "gconf" is not installed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can also compile iptux from source:

Install dependencies
**Ubuntu/Debian**

```
sudo apt-get install git libgtk2.0-dev libgconf2-dev g++ make autoconf libtool automake
```

**Fedora/Cent OS**

```
sudo yum install git gtk2-devel GConf2-devel gcc-c++ make autoconf libtool automake
```

Clone the directory from github

```
git clone git://github.com/iptux-src/iptux.git
```

Compile it and install

```
cd iptux
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

Execute the program

```
iptux
```

Comment: Done bro thank you so much i wasted my 3 day installing it. Finally. :)

Answer (score 0):

[iptux](http://www.ghacks.net/2010/09/17/instant-message-on-your-lan-with-iptux/) seems quite portable. You could compile it from sources and install it locally like for example [this tutorial tells you](http://geeksterminal.com/how-to-install-iptux/1106/).

Alternatively, you could manually download a [packaged version of iptux in rpm format](http://pkgs.org/download/iptux) and install it using the CentOS package manager.

```
rpm -i iptux-0.5.1-alt1_13.i586.rpm  OR  rpm -i iptux-0.5.1-alt1_13.x86_64.rpm
```